# docx4j - Why is the text truncated of spaces?

Tags: java, docx4j

Here is the code:

```
    P para = factory.createP();
    R run = factory.createR();
    Text text = factory.createText();

    text.setValue( "              abc                " );
    run.getContent().add( text );
    para.getContent().add( run );
    wordMLPack.getMainDocumentPart().add( para );
```

Here is the docx generated:

[image]

The heading and trailing spaces are all missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell docx4j to explicitly preserve whitespace in your `Text` instances (the underlying format is XML of course, which tends not to pay much heed to whitespace). Something like this:

```
text.setValue("              abc             ");
text.setSpace("preserve");
...
```

Comment: This should have been documented in docx4j wiki!